# PCI DSS - one server one primary function (different database engines)

Tags: pci-dss, databases, .net, wordpress

I looked at a few other questions similar to mine but they all talk about web/email/database on the same server.  My question is a bit different.  My business uses SQL Server 2008 as its backbone and .Net for the front end.  We are outsourcing a redesign to our web site and the outsourcing people want to build this using WordPress.  Which the people building this don't know how to connect it to SQL Server 20XX (even though I have seen articles that say it can, but I don't know how to do it either so I can't throw stones at it.) and will need to install MySQL.

So my question is, is it ok to have both SQL Server 20XX and MySQL running on the same server or does this break the one function one server rule?

Comment: hire real devs (that can figure out how to connect to SQL Server). And make sure you put a WAF in front of Wormpress

Answer (score 1):

The guidance in DSS 3.2 at least is "If server functions that need different security levels are located on the same server, the security level of the functions with higher security needs would be reduced due to the presence of the lower-security functions. Additionally, the server functions with a lower security level may introduce security weaknesses to other functions on the same server. By considering the security needs of different server functions as part of the system configuration standards and related processes, organizations can ensure that functions requiring different security levels don’t co-exist on the same server."

I'd examine the data going into each.  If it is comparable, you may be ok.  If, however, the WordPress (mysql) data is low security and the SQL Server data is not, you'd be hard-pressed to argue you're within this guidance, in my opinion (not a QSA)

I think I'd put it on a separate server just on general principles.  If they are on the same server, do your best to separate them - run them as different users, for instance, do your best to limit what the mysql database could do to the system or the SQL Server database.